# MySQL Results into Array

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to search, but couldn't really find exactly what I am trying to do. If it's been asked/answered, please forward me to the right page.

I have a site_configs table with just 3 columns;

### id === type === value

1  === imgPath === "../images/"

I am trying to put those values into an array so I can pull them for display or processing on a page in such a way that when I call the TYPE column, it displays the Value column.
`$configs['imgPath']` would spit out `../images/`.

I'm just not sure how to code the SELECT query to populate the array.

This is what I've tried, but it's not putting out any data:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM site_configs";
$site_config = array();
if($result = $mysqli->query($qry)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $site_config[$row['type']] = $row['value'];
    }
}
```

Then calling it like this

```
echo $site_config['imgPath'];
```

Thanks!

Rick

Comment: `select type, value from tableName`.  Then when you retrieve a row, get it as an associative array - use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, and then add the row to your results array.

Comment: I added my code above.

Comment: Your code looks fine. If you're not getting anything in `$site_config` it must mean the query is failing. What happens if you `echo $mysqli->error;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am assuming you are using plain php and not a framework. So something like

```
$query="SELECT * FROM your_table'" ;
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $query) ;

$new_array=array() ;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
         $new_array=["${row['type']}"] = $row['value'];
}
```